# Strange Cassandra ReadTimeoutExceptions, depending on which client is querying

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have a cluster of three Cassandra nodes with more or less default configuration. On top of that, I have a web layer consisting of two nodes for load balancing, both web nodes querying Cassandra all the time. After some time, with the data stored in Cassandra becoming non-trivial, one and only one of the web nodes started getting `ReadTimeoutException` on a specific query. The web nodes are identical in every way.

The query is very simple (`?` is placeholder for date, usually a few minutes before the current moment):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time > ? LIMIT 1 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

The table is created with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    user_id varchar,
    article_id varchar,
    time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, time));
CREATE INDEX articles_idx ON table(article_id);
```

When it times-out, the client waits for a bit more than 10s, which, not surprisingly, is the timeout configured in `cassandra.yaml` for most connects and reads.

There are a couple of things that are baffling me:

- the query only timeouts when one of the web nodes execute it - one of the nodes always fail, one of the nodes always succeed.
- the query returns instantaneously when I run it from `cqlsh` (although it seems it only hits one node when I run it from there)
- there are other queries issued which take 2-3 minutes (a lot longer than the 10s timeout) that do not timeout at all

I cannot trace the query in Java because it times out. Tracing the query in `cqlsh` didn't provide much insight. I'd rather not change the Cassandra timeouts as this is production system and I'd like to exhaust non-invasive options first. The Cassandra nodes all have plenty of heap, their heap is far from full, and GC times seem normal.

Any ideas/directions will be much appreciated, I'm totally out of ideas. Cassandra version is 2.0.2, using `com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:2.0.2` Java client.

Comment: How many rows are in this table?

Comment: Set a different consistency level in cqlsh and try again

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23: <100 million

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things I noticed:

1. While you are using `time` as a clustering key, it doesn't really help you because your query is not restricting by your partition key (`user_id`).  Cassandra only orders by clustering keys *within a partition*.  So right now your query is pulling back the first row which satisfies your WHERE clause, ordered by the hashed token value of `user_id`.  If you really do have tens of millions of rows, then I would expect this query to pull back data from the same `user_id` (or same select few) every time.
2. ***"although it seems it only hits one node when I run it from there"***  Actually, your queries *should* only hit one node when you run them.  Introducing network traffic into a query makes it really slow.  I think the default consistency in cqlsh is ONE.  This is where Carlo's idea comes into play.
3. What is the cardinality of `article_id`?  Remember, secondary indexes work the best on "middle-of-the-road" cardinality.  High (unique) and low (boolean) are both bad.
4. The [ALLOW FILTERING](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/allow-filtering-explained-2) clause should not be used in (production) application-side code.  Like ever.  If you have 50 million rows in this table, then ALLOW FILTERING is first pulling all of them back, and then trimming down the result set based on your WHERE clause.

Suggestions:

1. Carlo might be on to something with the suggestion of trying a different (lower) consistency level.  Try setting a consistency level of `ONE` in your application and see if that helps.
2. Either perform an ALLOW FILTERING query, *or* a secondary index query.  They both suck, but definitely do not do both together.  I would not use either.  But if I had to pick, I would expect a secondary index query to suck less than an ALLOW FILTERING query.
3. To solve this adequately at the scale in which you are describing, I would duplicate the data into a query table.  As it looks like you are concerned with organizing time-sensitive data, and in getting the most-recent data.  A query table like this should do it:

   `CREATE TABLE tablebydaybucket (
       user_id varchar,
       article_id varchar,
       time timestamp,
       day_bucket varchar,
       PRIMARY KEY (day_bucket , time))
   WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);`

Populate this table with your data, and then this query will work:

```
SELECT * FROM tablebydaybucket 
WHERE day_bucket='20150519' AND time > '2015-05-19 15:38:49-0500' LIMIT 1;
```

This will partition your data by `day_bucket`, and cluster your data by `time`.  This way, you won't need ALLOW FILTERING or a secondary index.  Also your query is guaranteed to hit only one node, and Cassandra will not have to pull all of your rows back and apply your WHERE clause after-the-fact.  And clustering on `time` in DESCending order, helps your most-recent rows come back quicker.

Comment: That was very insightful, thanks! The query is from an application health check - we expect continuous stream of data, and if there are no new rows, there's something wrong (therefore, receiving only records for one user_id is not a problem). Actual application code only selects by used_id.

In any case, nothing seems to explain why the query will persistently fail when executed from one box, and persistently succeed from another.